# GPU Monitor is missing on android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio 2.3 the GPU Monitor is located in motions tab.

[image]

In android studio 3.0 it has been replaced with Android profiler and it contains every thing in the old monitor tab except the GPU Monitor.

[image]

is there a way to enable GPU Monitor or a replacement in the android studio 3.0

Comment: Is that a programming question ?

Comment: yes, asking question android studio is very common on StackOverflow as it is directly linked with the development process.

Comment: Did you research ? Read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html)

Comment: of course, I did, this only available in version prior to AS 3.0. I mention this in my question.

Comment: Where did you see it's only for prior  A.S 3.0 ?  (don't make me fire up my AS and shame you lol - just joking)

Comment: I have both android studio 2.3 and 3.0. and I simply can't find it in 3.0. If you have AS 3.0 please do

Comment: awww sorry. I have 2.3.2 ... So no can't you. Good luck... Read carefully the documentation, you may even have to [perform dependencies check](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#byb)

Comment: And also AWWW bro... I just googled. Version 3.0 is not even stable yet. Don't wait you time please.

Comment: I know it is in beta. but as the AS team said they will not add new features. only bug fixes till the release.

Comment: Im not sure what was in https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html a few weeks earlier, but it says that the GPU profiler tool has been removed from AS 3.0 as of today :'(

Answer (score 5):

[image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-gpu.html

:'( this seems to be removed from Android Studio 3.0 . Not quite sure why